# $\text{Hom}(M \otimes_A N, L) \approx \mathscr{L}(M,N; L)$ The $A$-linear homs from the tensor product into $L$ are isomorphic with bilinear maps.

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products, linear-transformations

Let $M,N, L$ be two $A$-modules over a commutative ring $A$.  Let $\mathscr{L}(M,N;L)$ be the $A$-module of bilinear maps $M \times N \to L$.  Then $\text{Hom}_A(M \otimes_A N, L) \approx \mathscr{L}(M,N; L)$.  The map from the RHS to the LHS sends $\varphi$ to the unique $g : M\otimes_A N \to L$ such that $g(x\otimes y) = \varphi(x,y)$ in the definition of tensor product.  It's $A$-linear since $a \varphi + \gamma \mapsto !f$ such that $f(x \otimes y) = (a \varphi + \gamma)(x, y) = a \varphi(x,y) + \gamma(x,y) = a g(x\otimes y) + h(x \otimes y)$, where $\gamma \mapsto h$.  Since $ag + h$ satisfies the universal property, it must be unique, so the mapping is $A$-linear.

How would I define the natural inverse map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the other map is quite similar.

To $f \in \text{Hom}_A(M \otimes_A N, L)$, associate $g : M \times N \to L $ defined by $g(x,y) = f(x\otimes y).$ The application $g$ is clearly bilinear since $$g(x+z,y)=f((x+z)\otimes y) = f(x \otimes y + z \otimes y) = f(x \otimes y) + f(z \otimes y) = g(x,y) + g(z,y).$$ I let you check that the two maps are inverse of each other.